# Couchdb command not found

Tags: macos, couchdb, osx-mountain-lion, couchdb-futon

I would greatly appreciate help with CouchDb...

I have loaded CouchDB on my Mac running Mountain Lion (10.7.5). I believe I loaded the Lion version as the Mountain Lion option required I have 10.8. From the web browser CouchDb is running fine. I have a database running and collecting twitter data from a python script triggered nightly by a cronjob.

The problem is that I wanted to create an admin account, I made the changes required in the local.ini file but when I tried to restart the CouchDb server the command doesn't work.  My shell (either Bash or SH) does not recognize the command that is supposed to stop Couch.

I have tried both  `couchdb -d` and `couchdb stop` but I get the same message - `sh: couchdb: command not found`.

I Assumed that it was a path issue so I tried running the command in the CouchDb directory but get the same result. One issue that I am considering is that I have loaded Couch in the wrong directory but I have tried running this command in all of the CouchDb related directories I found.  I am sure I am missing something but any advice on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.  I considered reloading everything but I would like to use that as a last resort.

Comment: How did you load/install CouchDB? did you use homebrew? build-couchdb? download from the website? (For the sh command not found if you were in the directory, maybe you just needed `./couchdb -d`?)

Answer (score 0):

After I started Couch DB in OSX I can see its process with:

```
$ launchctl list | grep couchdb
4578    -   [0x0-0x101101].org.apache.couchdb
```

and I can stop it with:

```
$ launchctl stop '[0x0-0x101101].org.apache.couchdb'
```

Perhaps there is a simpler way, but I just checked it works. You can also see in the list of available `launchctl` commands (`launchctl help`) `load` described as "Load configuration files and/or directories". I am also quite sure that there is some REST API in Couch DB for stopping/restarting.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.  When I try launchctl list | grep couchdb - nothing happens. This makes me think that the install went awry or perhaps I have path issues?  I am not very strong in Unix so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Update - I was able to stop the process in Finder and then relaunch it from Finder.  I would still like to be able to do this from terminal but my immediate issue is solved.  Thanks for any help.